# Descending order using php

Tags: php

In the following codes, its coming numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .....and so on but i need that number in 5, 4, 3, 2,1 like that

```
 <?php
    //$events = $db->select("select * from main_menu where mm_menu='4' and mm_status='1' and mm_project='1' order by mm_order asc limit 0,10");
    $events = $db->select("select * from main_menu where mm_menu='4' and mm_status='1' and mm_project='1' order by mm_id desc");
    if (count($events) > 0) {
        $i = 1; 
        foreach ($events as $event_info) {
            $clsIn = ($i==1) ? "in" : "";
            $clsOut = ($i==1) ? "" : "collapsed";
            ?>
    
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $event_info['mm_title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo html_entity_decode($event_info['mm_content']);?></td>
            </tr>    
    
            <?php 
            $i++;
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: Please try and format your question code properly.  Also you will need to add some explanation of what you want and what the problems you have in achieving it.  Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more ideas.

Comment: its coming numbers 1, 2, 3, 4,5 .....and so on but i need that number in 5, 4, 3, 2,1 like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count down, set `$i` to the total number of events, and then decrement it:

First:

```
$i = count($events);
```

and then at the end of the loop:

```
$i--;
```